# How do I include a custom count in a MySQL SELECT result set?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have the following two tables:

```
TABLE: area
*City_ID   *Number   Name
--------   -------   ----
SUR        1         Fleetwood
SUR        2         Whalley
SUR        3         Guildford
SUR        4         Newton
SUR        5         Cloverdale
SUR        6         South Surrey
ABB        1         Abbotsford East
ABB        2         Abbotsford West
ABB        3         Aberdeen
ABB        4         Bradner
ABB        5         Central Abbotsford
ABB        6         Matsqui
ABB        7         Poplar
ABB        8         Sumas Mountain
ABB        9         Sumas Prairie

TABLE: city
*ID        Name
---        ----
SUR        Surrey
ABB        Abbotsford
LAN        Langley
```

Using the following statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT area.City_ID, city.Name
FROM area
INNER JOIN city
WHERE area.City_ID = city.ID
```

I get:

```
SELECT:
City_ID    city.Name
-------    ---------
SUR        Surrey
ABB        Abbotsford
```

But how do I SELECT the following:

```
SELECT:
City_ID    city.Name    area_COUNT
-------    ---------    ----------
SUR        Surrey       6
ABB        Abbotsford   9
```

where `area_COUNT` is the number of rows in `area` for each corresponding `City_ID`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT city.City_ID, city.Name, COUNT(*)
FROM area
INNER JOIN city
WHERE area.City_ID = city.ID
GROUP BY city.ID
```

Comment: please see comment at answer [11519121](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518995/how-do-i-include-a-custom-count-in-a-mysql-select-result-set/11519121#11519121) below

Answer (score 1):

You should also add Name in Group by clause

```
SELECT area.City_ID, city.Name, count(*) as area_COUNT 
FROM area 
INNER JOIN city 
WHERE area.City_ID = city.ID 
GROUP BY area.City_ID,City.Name
```

Comment: @AnaBan He's right. The SQL spec requires all non aggregate columns to be listed in the group by.

Comment: MySQL allows not listing them. If the column doens't have the same value for all grouped rows, then an arbitrary choice will be made.

Answer (score 0):

add group by at the end

```
SELECT area.City_ID, city.Name, count(*) as area_COUNT
FROM area
INNER JOIN city
WHERE area.City_ID = city.ID
GROUP BY area.City_ID
```

Comment: thanks, shankhan, but i saw @MvG 's answer first. thanks again, though. :D

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT:

SELECT city.City_ID, city.Name, COUNT(*)
FROM area
INNER JOIN city
WHERE area.City_ID = city.ID
GROUP BY city.ID

Comment: Still you need to add Name column in the group by clause